# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error RSA Android app and Java Server

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I am currently coding a RSA Implementation for my app and the server.
The goal is to send encrypted messages to the server and back to the client the app.
The same class is also used in the App.
I guess the problem is with the conversion of the ciphertext into string and back with base 64 this is I guess the error I tried to solve but I didn't worked so now I am asking here.
I would be glad if you take some time and review my code.
I tried with base 64 but i didn't worked.

```
public class RSA {
    public static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    public static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "MD5withRSA";

    private static final String PUBLIC_KEY = "RSAPublicKeyS";
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY = "RSAPrivateKeyS";
    static java.util.Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
    static Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();

    public static byte[] decryptBASE64(String key) throws Exception {
        return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(key);
    }

    public static String encryptBASE64(byte[] key) throws Exception {
        return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(key);
    }


    public static String sign(String dataS, String privateKey) throws Exception {

        byte[] data = dataS.getBytes();
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(privateKey);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);

        PrivateKey priKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        signature.initSign(priKey);
        signature.update(data);

        return encryptBASE64(signature.sign());
    }

    public static boolean verify(String dataS, String publicKey, String sign)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] data = dataS.getBytes();
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(publicKey);

        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);

        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        signature.initVerify(pubKey);
        signature.update(data);

        return signature.verify(decryptBASE64(sign));
    }


    public static String decryptByPrivateKey(String dataS, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] data = decryptBASE64(dataS);
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        byte[] res = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return res.toString();
    }


    public static byte[] decryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }

    public static String encryptByPublicKey(String dataString, String key)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);
        byte[] data = decryptBASE64(dataString);


        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        byte[] res = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return encryptBASE64(res);
    }

    public static String encryptByPrivateKey(String dataString, String key)
            throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);
        byte[] data = dataString.getBytes();
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        byte[] res = cipher.doFinal(data);
 
        return res.toString();
    }

    public static String getPrivateKey(Map<String, Object> keyMap)
            throws Exception {
        Key key = (Key) keyMap.get(PRIVATE_KEY);

        return encryptBASE64(key.getEncoded());
    }

    public static String getPublicKey(Map<String, Object> keyMap)
            throws Exception {
        Key key = (Key) keyMap.get(PUBLIC_KEY);

        return encryptBASE64(key.getEncoded());
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> initKey() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator
                .getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        keyPairGen.initialize(2048);

        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();

        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();

        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

        Map<String, Object> keyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);

        keyMap.put(PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);
        keyMap.put(PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        return keyMap;
    }
}
```

The following error which i got is

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at byte[] res = cipher.doFinal(data); 
Method decryptByPublicKey()
```

Comment: Why do you use RSA for encryption? You can use RSA for signature or Key Encapsulation Mechanism like RSA-KEM. Your code is not verifiable since you did not provide a complete running program ( minimal code!) that indicate the error line where this is missing now!

Comment: I have added where the error happened. I have read also that in production you exchange with RSA an encrypted session key and then you use AES256 as example. i need to do encryption I can't send the session key unencrypted. Or do you have another option to securely transfer a session key then I would be open to use another method.

Comment: That is [RSA-KEM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76857/18298)

Comment: Thanks I will take a look over it

Comment: Why do you have two encryption functions? You need only one!